# BFS Shortest Path Lemma 22.3

Tags: graph, breadth-first-search

First the notation:

Let `d[v]` is a distance between root of the BFS tree and vertex `v`

[This book](http://aris.me/contents/teaching/data-mining-ds-2016/resources/clrs-bfs.pdf) states the following lemma:

During BFS the queue `Q` contains the vertices: `v_1, v_2, ..., v_r`, where

- `v_1` is the head of `Q`
- `v_r` is the tail of `Q`

Then:

1. `d[v_r] <= d[v_1] + 1`
2. `d[v_i] <= d[v_(i + 1)]` for `i = 1, 2, ..., r - 1`

I do not understand first statement. In words it says: the last vertex `v_r` that BFS added to the queue has shorter distance to the `root` than the first vertex `v_1` that we added to the queue. Visually:

```
      root
      /  \
    v_1  v_2
    /
   v_3
   /
 v_r
```

How it can be possible?

Comment: I think the point of this Lemma is that at any tine in BFS, the Q would not contain items that are more than 1 level deeper than the rest. So because queue would be filled with `v_1, v_2, v_3..., v_r` - `v_r` is the last one to be added, which could be at the maximum 1 level deeper.

Answer (score 2):

You're misreading the statement.

```
d[v_r] <= d[v_1] + 1
```

means that the depth of `v_r` can be **no greater** than one more than the depth of `v_1`. `v_r` can be on the same level of the BFS tree or on the level below, but never farther than that. Relabeling your tree slightly,

```
      root
      /  \
    v_a  v_b
    /
   v_c
   /
 v_x
```

`v_x` can never be in the queue at the same time as `v_a` or `v_b`, but `v_c` can.

The only way `d[v_r]` could be **less** than `d[v_1]` is if you enqueued a previously-visited vertex.